# How can I examine the stack frame with GDB?

Tags: gdb, stack

Right now I've been using GDB to disassemble a binary file and check out different registers and whatnot. Is there an easy command to examine everything on the stack? Can this be limited to everything in a function?

Comment: This should be of some help to you : http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring07/V22.0474-001/misc/gdb-refcard.pdf. You can always use "frame" command to jump between the frames.

Comment: The link requires login now. Here's an archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20141222091304/http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring07/V22.0474-001/misc/gdb-refcard.pdf

Answer (score 98, accepted):

For the current stack frame:

- **info frame** lists general info about the frame (where things start in memory, etc.)
- **info args** lists arguments to the function
- **info locals** lists local variables stored in the frame

Comment: what if I have a variable also called frame?

Comment: @Jeoker `info frame` is always going to tell you about the frame. If you want info about a variable you'd have to use other subcommands like `info locals <name>`, or other commands entirely like `print`

Answer (score 112):

You can view the contents of the stack with **`x/10x $sp`**

This will print the top 10 elements of the stack.

Comment: What version of GDB is this? I can't get gdb to use registers as command arguments on GDB 7.7-0ubuntu3.1

Comment: This is answer tells you how actually look at the bytes on the stack frame, which I've had some trouble finding out how to do.  Thanks!

Comment: But this will print the element pointed by `$sp` and the 9 elements **after** it, that is (if the stack grows downwards like for example in x86) 9 elements that are not actually used by the program yet. Right?

Comment: @cYrus $sp points to the top of the stack, i.e. the lower address. You're probably thinking of $bp which stores the bottom address of the stack.

Answer (score 85):

- `bt` (or `backtrace`) will give you a call stack.
- `frame <args>` will select a frame on the call stack for inspection
- `info frame <args>` will give you information about a specific frame from the stack. When called without arguments it will display the currently selected frame
- `info locals` can give you information about any local variables on the stack.

Comment: frame <args> also selects a frame. `info frame <addr>` is used to examine the frame without selecting it

Answer (score 9):

- just try `bt full`, and you will get all frames and locals
- input `frame x`, to enter the *x* frame

by the way, you should know about *process address space* and what it is composed:
[linux virtual address space](https://gabrieletolomei.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/program_in_memory2.png), this will help you understand how the frame is used.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example adding a link to what is _process address space_ and elaborate how it can help to solve this question might be helpful.