# GDB: Adding contents of stack to auto display

Tags: gdb

In gdb it is possible to show let's say 5 last values on the stack via:

```
(gdb) x/5x $sp
0x7fffffffde40: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0xffffe1e9  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffde50: 0x00000000
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770889/how-can-i-examine-the-stack-frame-with-gdb/13977340#13977340). However I would like to add it to auto display and was not able to come up with a solution. My try so far yields only the address of the last element on the stack:

```
(gdb) display/5x $sp
1: /x $sp = 0x7fffffffde40
```

as `display` seems just to skip `5`.

Is is possible to show the content of the stack in the auto display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb's `display` command acts like the `print` command, and they differ a bit from the `x` command:

- `display` and `print` don't use repeat counts in the `/format` option. If you give a count, `display` will ignore it, and `print` will complain about it.
- `display` and `print` print the value of the expression, but `x` takes the value of the expression, treats it as an address, and prints the value in memory at that address. That's why, in your example, `display /x $sp` outputs `0x7fffffffde40` and `x/x $sp` outputs `0x00000001`.

There are a couple of ways to get `display` (and `print`) to show a series of values starting at a given address:

- prefix the expression (which is presumably an address, or a variable or register whose value is an address) with `{type}`, where `type` is an array type:

  ```
  display {int[5]}$sp
  ```
- use the `@` operator in the expression. `@` represents an array starting at the address of its left-hand argument and containing the number of elements specified by its right-hand argument:

  ```
  print *(int *)$sp@5
  ```